# latex bibtex citation caption list of figures

Tags: floats, bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I am using the bibtex userpackage. When I cite a reference in the figure caption it shows the name, e.g. 'latexcompanion' in the Lift of Figures instead of the reference number [] that is shown in the caption.

```
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues with what you want to do. So, please show a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that we can actually diagnose the problem.

Comment: I suspect the error lies somewhere in this code

  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents\relax\clearpage}
  \iftotalfigures {\pagestyle{plain}\listoffigures\relax\clearpage}\fi
  \iftotaltables {\pagestyle{plain}\listoftables\relax\clearpage}\fi
  \@ifpackageloaded{todonotes}{\pagestyle{plain}\listoftodos\relax\clearpage}{}
  \ifprinterfriendly
    \cleartooddpage
  \else
    \cleartorecto
  \fi
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{ruled}
}

Comment: (1) please **edit** your original question to provide any additional clarifying information. This makes it more prominent for other readers who may be able to help. (2) Please create it as a MWE, as I mentioned in the previous comment, which asks you to boil down your question to a minimal compilable document that exhibits the problem. (Minimal to the best of your ability.) (3) While you are at it, is the generated `.lof` file the same in the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error lies somewhere in this code. I tried to just use '\listoffigures' by itself and that worked fine. But when using the code below, the described problem occurs.

```
  \clearpage
  {\pagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents\relax\clearpage}
  \iftotalfigures {\pagestyle{plain}\listoffigures\relax\clearpage}\fi
  \iftotaltables {\pagestyle{plain}\listoftables\relax\clearpage}\fi
  \@ifpackageloaded{todonotes}{\pagestyle{plain}\listoftodos\relax\clearpage}{}
  \ifprinterfriendly
    \cleartooddpage
  \else
    \cleartorecto
  \fi
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{ruled}
}
```